# How to keep userinfo for each request globally for the application in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on nodejs (expressjs) application. After authentication a random generated token is return to app. That token is used for authenticating further requests. After authenticating how do we keep user info till completing request. Can we use session?

Comment: you can add into `request` object like `req.user = getUserFromToken(req.headers.token);`

Comment: ok thank you @ArifKhan

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** (as mentioned in comments)

You can store your user data manually in the `request` object `req.user = userData`

**Option 2**

Using an external library like `passport.js` allows you to handle the whole authentication part and automatically saves the authenticated user into the `request` object (`req.user`) for every single request (as long as the user authenticated)